# Unable to install libatlas-base-dev on Pi 4 B because of unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation, apt, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I am using Raspberry Pi 4 model B, with Raspbian v 10 buster.

I was following [this tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi) to set up TensorFlow object detection on my Raspberry Pi and PsEye camera.

The problem is, when I try to install `libatlas-base-dev` I get an error:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/tensor_flow $ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libatlas-base-dev : Depends: libatlas3-base (= 3.10.3-8+rpi1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I've tried `sudo apt-update` and `sudo apt-get -f install` without any luck. I am able to install most of other software.

I also tried `sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base` with the following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libatlas3-base : Depends: libblas-common but it is not installable

So I also tried `sudo apt-get install libblas-common` with further errors:

> E: Unable to locate package libatlas-common

Comment: `Unable to locate package libatlas-common` that's the cause of the whole problem - that's what you need to investigate ... it's odd that you try to install `libblas-common` and it says `libatlas-common` can't be found

Comment: on further investigation, seems `libblas-common` exists in jessie and stretch but not in buster - looks like the tutorial you followed is too old for pi4 (which requires buster)

Comment: @JaromandaX that's very unfortunate. But help for your investigation!

Do you know if it is possible to use tensorflow to detect objects on buster?

Comment: no idea - perhaps search for *tensorflow on raspberry pi 4* - see if there's any tutorials on how to install it on the pi4

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately, there aren't many. Even less (or nothing) when you use USB camera instead of Pi Camera (my case). The only one I found for USB camera is the one I listed which uses libatlas :(

Comment: Show I downgrade to stretch?

Comment: you can't. You have a pi4

Comment: @JaromandaX  How is it possible such common library used as dependency for i.e. OpenCV is not possible to be installed on strable Rasbian distribution? It's hard to believe it O_o

Comment: when I said *seems libblas-common exists in jessie and stretch but not in buster* did you noticed I did **not** say this was Raspbian ... I was actually talking about **Debian** on which Raspbian is based - and if "big brother Debian" doesn't have it, then it's not going to be in Raspbian either - (note: libblas-common was NEVER an actual library in the first place - but that detail is only of mild interest)

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not really familiar with libblas. All I know, without libatlas-base-dev (and every single OpenCV/TensorFlow tutorial wants me to install it), I cannot use openCV properly (errors like `libcblas.so.3:` in `cv2` and many others - for which everybody tells to install `libatlas-base-dev`). Which seems extremely unlikely that major stable Raspbian/Debian distribution breaks OpenCV/TensorFlow support all together.

Comment: `libatlas-base-dev` is available in buster, it depends on `libatlas3-base` which only depends on `libblas-common` in stretch or earlier, and has no such dependency in buster

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok, I see now. Than why is it not possible to install `libatlas-base-dev` on buster? Am I typing something wrong? Because as you see, when I try to install `libatlas-base-dev` it goes down to `The following packages have unmet dependencies: libatlas3-base : Depends: libblas-common but it is not installable` which should not be even required in buster, right? Some additional update/fix of repositories list or something like that? I'm out of options.

Comment: There's something wrong with your apt setup in that case - libatlas3-base depends on `libc6 (>= 2.27), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.0), libgfortran5` in raspbian buster - have you added sources to your apt settings - perhaps you could show your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Bingo! There was `deb https://raspbian.snips.ai/stretch stable main` listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which must have caused the miss-match (snips does not have buster compatibility and it was recommended to use `stretch` there for now - and I forgot I've added it days ago). Can you make an answer from your comment so I can approve it?

Comment: Not really, how many people are going to add a stretch repository to their buster install? You can self-answer - you have more detail on how you broke it :p

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `@Jaromanda X` I now know that the problem was due to wrong apt setup.

To be precise, some libraries still do not support buster and in case of Snips (for offline speech detection), the [suggested workaround](https://github.com/snipsco/snips-issues/issues/161) was to switch to stretch repository for it (namely, `https://raspbian.snips.ai/stretch`).

After doing so, while trying to install `libatlas-base-dev`, which in buster should no longer depends on `libblas-common`, due to `https://raspbian.snips.ai/stretch` I was actually trying to get the older version which was still using it. And of course, after longer time I forgot I've added this deb in the first place.

So the way to go was to remove it from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Credits to `@Jaromanda X` for finding the source of the problem.

Comment: I'm not expert with it, but you can use apt pinning (I think) to have your `snips` come from `https://raspbian.snips.ai/stretch` and not effect the system like that

Comment: @JaromandaX that's actually sweet! ;) I was thinking about first installing the snips this "dirty way" than disabling the stretch deb (in case I would have to re-do the installation)... but I prefer the way with `apt pinning` much better and will look into it.